# Div not opening on the screen in Ionic 3

Tags: jquery, css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have HTML page which has a `div`. If I test it on JS Fiddle, like if I open `div` from top of page or even if I scroll down to the bottom and open from there, **it opens in front of the screen.**

See below code -  click on `show` , `hide` , scroll down and you can see same button at the bottom, click on them to open / close `<div class="custom-menu">...</div>`.

```js
    $(".showhide-menu li").unbind().click(function() {
      switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {
        case "show":
          $(".custom-menu").show();
          break;

          case "hide":
            $(".custom-menu").hide();
            break;
      }
      });
```

```css
.custom-menu {
        display: none;
        z-index: 1000;
        position: fixed;
        
        top:20%; right:50%;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 120px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
        -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='custom-menu'>
    <li>Menu</li>
    <li data-action = "first">Clone</li>
    <li data-action = "second">Remove</li>
    <li data-action = "third">Edit</li>
  </div>

  <ul class='showhide-menu'>
    <li data-action = "show">Show</li>
    <li data-action = "hide">Hide</li>
  </ul>

<div>
  Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world.......... Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world.......... Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world.......... Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world.......... Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world.......... Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world.......... Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world.......... Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world.......... Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world.......... Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world.......... Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world..........
</div>

<ul class='showhide-menu'>
  <li data-action = "show">Show</li>
  <li data-action = "hide">Hide</li>
</ul>
```

When I try to do same in ionic, div always opens at the `page top` (imagine I have scrolled down) and not in front of the screen. Below is my code:

`home.html`

```
<ion-content (ionScroll)="getScrollTop()">

  <div class='custom-menu'>
    <li>Menu</li>
    <li data-action = "first">Clone</li>
    <li data-action = "second">Remove</li>
    <li data-action = "third">Edit</li>
  </div>

  <ul class='showhide-menu'>
    <li data-action = "show">Show</li>
    <li data-action = "hide">Hide</li>
  </ul>

<div>
  Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world  worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello  worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world
</div>

<ul class='showhide-menu'>
  <li data-action = "show">Show</li>
  <li data-action = "hide">Hide</li>
</ul>


</ion-content>
```

`home.ts`

```
import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
declare var $: any;

/**
 * Generated class for the TestdivPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

//@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-testdiv',
  templateUrl: 'testdiv.html',
})
export class TestdivPage {
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

  public scrollPost: number = 0;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    $(".custom-menu").hide();
    $(".showhide-menu").show();

    console.log('ionViewDidLoad TestdivPage');
  }

  ngOnInit()
  {

    $(".showhide-menu li").unbind().click(function() {
      switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {
        case "show":
          $(".custom-menu").show();
          break;

          case "hide":
            $(".custom-menu").hide();
            break;
      }
      });

  }

  getScrollTop() {
    this.scrollPost = this.content.scrollTop;
    console.log(this.scrollPost);
  }
}
```

`home.scss`

```
.custom-menu {
        display: none;
        z-index: 1000;
        position: fixed;

        top:20%; right:50%;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 120px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
        -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
      }
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use angular click function ngClick instead of binding and use ionic predefined components with angular framework.
playing directly with DOM is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  menuFilter = false;

  showHideMenu(filter){
    switch(filter){
      case 'show':
         this.menuFilter = true;
         break;
      case 'hide':
         this.menuFilter = false;
         break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='custom-menu'>
    <li>Menu</li>
    <li data-action="first">Clone</li>
    <li data-action="second">Remove</li>
    <li data-action="third">Edit</li>
</div>

<ul class='showhide-menu'>
    <li (click)="showHideMenu('show')">Show</li>
    <li (click)="showHideMenu('hide')"> Hide</li>
</ul>

<div *ngIf="menuFilter">
    Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world
</div>
```

You can use two data-binding and angular functions and events to get this thing work